# VS 2015 does'nt integrate Git command (even though installing msysgitVS.exe)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

After installing VS 2015 and installing

> msysgitVS.exe

using recommanded *Third Party Tools* ; git command prompt is still not integrated nor recognized. When doing :

Actions > Open Command Prompt, and typing a git command, following message appear :

> 'git' is not recognized as internal or external command

How come git is not as well integrated in VS 2015 as it is in VS 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a previous installation of Git? I have been struggling with this too and it seems VisualStudio 2015 installs git version 1.9.5 without knowing about your previous git installation. That caused all kinds of trouble for me.

The command I used to verify my git version installed by VS2015 (after going through the process of uninstalling all the instances of git):

```
C:\>git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0
```

For me this caused a crash every time I right clicked in Explorer, as this would bring up the "Git GUI here" option (which obviously crashed).

So, to sum up:

1. Try uninstalling all versions of git.
2. Also delete the folders containing the old git installation. (The VS2015 git installation destroyed my uninstall information for my old git installation, so I had to manually remove it)
3. Then try the VS2015 git installation again, by clicking Third Party Tools just like you did. That did it for me.